# is there a way, in firefox, to take a screenshot of the current window, using only one keyboard shortcut

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, browser-addons, screenshot

I am aware of the built-in firefox screenshots, but they require the use of the mouse and at least 3 clicks.

Is there any way on vanilla firefox or using extensions to take a screenshot, that gets saved to downloads, on a single key combination? (say, ctrl-alt-s, but the combination itself makes no difference)

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: windows and linux. on linux, i can get a window only screenshot, that is good enough

Comment: ideally I would prefer a solution that works on Firefox on any operating system

Comment: You don't need the mouse (from an accessibility point of view that's important). Ctrl-Shift-S and tab gets your there. Just setting the record straight, I know it doesn't answer your question ;).

Answer (score 2):

> I am aware of the built-in firefox screenshots, *but they require the use of the mouse and at least 3 clicks.*

This is one of several reasons why I never bothered to use Firefox Screenshots.

If you are looking for a single keyboard shortcut that triggers a file to be saved with your image, your best option is using operating system keyboard shortcuts. These vary between operating systems but are still fairly easy to remember.

**Windows 10:**

Take screenshot of the entire screen and save it to `%userprofile%\Pictures\Screenshots`.

<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd>

**macOS:**

Take screenshot of the entire screen and save it to the desktop.

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>

Comment: do you happen to know a way that also works on windows 7?

Comment: Unfortunately, this shortcut only exists in Windows 8.1 and 10. For Windows 7, I used to hit Print Screen, then pasted into Paint and saved my PNG from there. You could install a third-party app to allow you to do this with a single keyboard shortcut: Snagit and Greenshot both allow you to do this but only Greenshot is free.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above I'd recommend trying an application like greenshot or sharex. They both have the option for one keypress screenshots and more. They can capture a selected region, window, the entire desktop, you name it! They also have a ton of additional options for screenshots which allows you to upload it to an account like Google drive, imgur, etc. I mainly use it for copying/pasting screenshots because I don't want to clutter my pc with tons of random screenshots.